# Is it possible write multiple JArrays to file with JsonTextWriter as one JArray?

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, async-await, json.net

Using Json.NET, I have to read data from data base part by page in a loop, then serialize each page **asynchronously** to a JSON file that should contain a single array of items from all pages.  I am currently doing that by serializing the items from each page to an intermediate `JArray`, then writing the `JArray` to the file asynchronously using `JsonTextWriter`.  However, this results in the JSON file containing a sequence of arrays rather than a single array.  I need the sequence of JArrays to be written as a single array, how can I do this?

Here is my current code:

```
do
{
   resPre = await _dbService.GetAllByPageAndSizeAsync(page, pageSize);
   var dataOut = resPre?.Items;
   if (dataOut?.Count > 0)
   {
      var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataOut);
      var rawJson = JArray.Parse(json);
      await rawJson.WriteToAsync(writer);
   }
   page++;
} 
while (resPre?.Items?.Count > 0);
```

File fact result:

```
[
 {
  "id": 1
 },
 {
  "id": 2
 },
 {
  "id": 3
 }
][
 {
  "id": 4
 },
 {
  "id": 5
 },
 {
  "id": 6
 }
]
```

Expect:

```
[
 {
  "id": 1
 },
 {
  "id": 2
 },
 {
  "id": 3
 },
 {
  "id": 4
 },
 {
  "id": 5
 },
 {
  "id": 6
 }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to **directly** write multiple JArrays as a single array, however you could reorganize your code to manually write the array start, data items, and array end asynchronously as follows:

```
await using (var stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, bufferSize: 4096, useAsync: true))
using (var textWriter = new StreamWriter(stream, leaveOpen : true)) // use leaveOpen = true to ensure the file stream is closed asynchronously via the `await using` statement.
using (var writer = new JsonTextWriter(textWriter) { CloseOutput = false, Formatting = Formatting.Indented })
{
    int pageSize = 3; // Or whatever
    await writer.WriteStartArrayAsync(); // Write the array beginning asynchronously
    for (int page = 0; true; page++)
    {
        var resPre = await _dbService.GetAllByPageAndSizeAsync(page, pageSize);
        if (resPre == null || resPre.Items == null || resPre.Items.Count == 0)
            break; // No more data pages to serialize
        foreach (var item in resPre.Items)
            await JToken.FromObject(item).WriteToAsync(writer);  // Write each array item asynchronously.
    } 
    await writer.WriteEndArrayAsync(); // Write the array end asynchronously
}
```

Notes:

- I am assuming that `resPre.Items` is an `IEnumerable<T>` for some type `T`.
- Rather than serializing each item to a string, then parsing the string to a `JToken`, use [`JToken.FromObject()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_FromObject.htm) to skip the intermediate string representation.

Mockup fidle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BiQaYQ).

---

**As an alternative**, as of .NET 6 Microsoft's [System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/overview) serializer has [built-in support for `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/serialization/6.0/iasyncenumerable-serialization) so as long as your `Item` type is serializable using this serializer, you could rewrite your code to use this serializer as follows:

```
using System.Text.Json;

async IAsyncEnumerable<Item> GetItems()
{
    int pageSize = 3; // Or whatever
    for (int page = 0; true; page++)
    {
        var resPre = await _dbService.GetAllByPageAndSizeAsync(page, pageSize);
        if (resPre == null || resPre.Items == null || resPre.Items.Count == 0)
            break; // No more data pages to serialize
        foreach (var item in resPre.Items)
            yield return item;
    } 
}
await using (var stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, bufferSize: 4096, useAsync: true))
{
    await System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeAsync(
        stream, GetItems(), 
        new JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true } );
}
```

Mockup fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OwxymS).

Answer (score -1):

Obviously you could just combine them all into one list and serialize that. But that might be inefficient.

You just need to loop the items and write them individually, along with the start and end of the array.

```cs
var ser = JsonSerializer.CreateDefault();
writer.WriteStartArray();
while (true)
{
    resPre = await _dbService.GetAllByPageAndSizeAsync(page, pageSize);
    if(!(resPre?.Items?.Count > 0))
        break;
    foreach (var item in resPre.Items)
        ser.SerializeObject(writer, item);

    page++;
} 
writer.WriteEndArray();
```

Unfortunately, Json.NET does not properly support async at the moment.

---

Another option is to create an enumerable, and pass that to `JsonConvert`

```cs
async Task<Enumerable<YourClass>> GetAllData(int pageSize)
{
    int page = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        var resPre = await _dbService.GetAllByPageAndSizeAsync(page, pageSize);
        if (!(resPre?.Items?.Count > 0))
            yield break;

        foreach (var item in resPre.Items)
            yield return item;

        page++
    }
}
```

```cs
ser.SerializeObject(writer, await GetAllData(pageSize));
```